# Reformulation of matrix optimization. Is it equivalent?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, solution-verification, least-squares

Consider the linear least squares problem:

$${\bf x_o}=\min_{\bf x}\|{\bf Mx-b}\|_2^2$$
can be solved by normal equations:
$${\bf x_o} = ({\bf M}^T{\bf M})^{-1}{\bf M}^T{\bf b}$$

Assuming $\bf M$ has no zero eigenvalues, and we modify, to solve:

$${\bf x_o}=\min_{\bf x}\|{\bf M}^k({\bf Mx-b})\|_2^2, k \in \mathbb Z^+$$

We should be sure to not change the solution $\bf x$, right?

Or do I need some extra condition on $\bf M$ for this to be true?

Or is it mostly only theoretically true and can affect solution speed and accuracy, also?

Comment: It's ok I fixed it all on my own. The idea sped up the solving several times for my particular class of matrices.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason you got downvoted is that if
$$\bf{M}^k\bf{M}\bf{x}$$
is defined then $\bf{M}$ must be a square matrix but then if $\bf{M}$ has no zero eigenvalues the problem has the unique minimum of $0$ when
$$\bf{x_0}=\bf{M}^{-1}\bf{b}$$

Comment: This doesn't help at all. You are not answering the question. I don't want to solve it. I just want to reformulate it.

Comment: In my limited experience a least squares problem implies an overdetermined system where matrix $\bf{M}$ has more rows than columns. But if you can multiply $\bf{M}\bf{M}$ that implies that it's not what I would consider a linear least squares problem but $n$ equations in $n$ unknowns. Obviously it wouldn't change the solution $\bf{x}$ because it's still equivalent to $\bf{M}\bf{x}=\bf{b}$ given nonsingular $\bf{M}$.

Comment: It's ok I fixed it all on my own. Sped up the solving several times for my particular class of matrices.